# Python SQL Query Error "psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "where"

Tags: python, sql, syntax-error, psycopg2

I am trying to write a simple sql query to return columns if student_id is matched and if another column is true as following:

```
    student_info_query = """
    select student_age from students sd
    inner join registers rv on sd.id = rv.student_id
    where rv.is_paid is true and rv.is_accepted is true
    where sd.id = {}
    where sd.class_id = {}
    """ 
    query_df = db_connection.query(student_info_query.format(std_id, cls_id))
```

but I keep receiving error "psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "where" LINE 5 where sd.id = 182"
I also tried with `rv.is_accepted = true` and `rv.is_accepted = TRUE`, but still same error
Not sure where the error is comming from.
any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the syntax error pointed out by the other answers, don't use `.format` (or any other form of string concatenation or interpolation) when dealing with queries.

Instead, you should be using parametrized queries.

Not only this will let the database/ORM engine deal with types correctly, it will also protect your application from various [SQL injection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#sql-injection) attacks.

Using a parametrized query this code would look something like (assuming you are using psycopg2)

```py
student_info_query = """
    select student_age from students sd
    inner join registers rv on sd.id = rv.student_id
    where rv.is_paid is true and rv.is_accepted is true
    and sd.id = %s and sd.class_id = %s
""" 

curor = db_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(student_info_query, (std_id, cls_id))
query_df = cursor.fetchone()
```

You should really read the docs: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple `where` statements.  I believe you want something more like:

```
student_info_query = """
select student_age from students sd
inner join registers rv on sd.id = rv.student_id
where rv.is_paid is true and rv.is_accepted is true
and sd.id = {}
and sd.class_id = {}
""" 
query_df = db_connection.query(student_info_query.format(std_id, cls_id))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that indeed solve my problem but not I am getting another error "psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: character varying = integer" but my std_id is string and not integer. Also cls_id is string.

Comment: The problem is that your query string will look like `sd.id = 182` whereas it needs to have `sd.id = '182'` if the column in the DB is of string type. Rather than doing string substitution, it would be better to use a parametrised query, which takes care of aspects like quoting for you. It is also more secure (avoids SQL injection). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python